# Regular expression that matches number in string but not percentages

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to know if there is a regular expression for testing for the presence of numbers in strings that:

- Matches `Lorem 20 Ipsum`
- Matches `Lorem 2,5 Ipsum`
- Matches `Lorem 20.5 Ipsum`
- Does **not** match `Lorem 2% Ipsum`
- Does **not** match `Lorem 20.5% Ipsum`
- Does **not** match `Lorem 20,5% Ipsum`
- Does **not** match `Lorem 2 percent Ipsum`
- Does **not** match `Lorem 20.5 percent Ipsum`
- Does **not** match `Lorem 20,5 percent Ipsum`
- Matches `Lorem 20 Ipsum 2% dolor`
- Matches `Lorem 2,5 Ipsum 20.5% dolor`
- Matches `Lorem 20.5 Ipsum 20,5% dolor`

That is, a regular expression that can tell me if in a string there is one or many numbers, but not as percentage value.

I've tried something as `/[0-9\.,]+[^%]/`, but this not seems to work, I think because *digits then not a percentage sign* match also the `20` in the string `20%`. Additionally, I don't know how to tell *not the entire `percent` string* in addition to the `%` char.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
\b                     -- word boundary
\d+                    -- one or more digits
(?:\.\d+)?             -- optionally followed by a period and one or more digits
\b                     -- word boundary
\s+                    -- one or more spaces
(?!%|percent)          -- NOT followed by a % or the word 'percent'
```

--EDIT--

The meat here is the use of a "negative lookahead" on the final line that causes the match to fail if any of a percent-sign or the literal "percent" occurs after a number and one or more spaces. Other uses of negative lookahead in JavaScript RegExps can be found at [Negative lookahead Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851921/negative-lookahead-regular-expression)

--2ND EDIT--
Congrats to Enrico for solving the most general case but while his solution below is correct, it contains several extraneous operators. Here is the most succinct solution.

```
(                         -- start capture
  \d+                     -- one or more digits
  (?:[\.,]\d+)?           -- optional period or comma followed by one or more digits
  \b                      -- word boundary
  (?!                     -- start negative lookahead
    (?:[\.,]\d+)          -- must not be followed by period or comma plus digits
  |                       --    or
    (?:                   -- start option group
      \s?%                -- optional space plus percent sign
    |                     --   or
      \spercent           -- required space and literal 'percent'
    )                     -- end option group
  )                       -- end negative lookahead
)                         -- end capture group
```

Comment: You miss the , as decimal separator. (Just a tip)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the OP did not ask to extract numbers nor how many might occur in a string, only that they exist. My answer will match strings that contain numbers which are not percentages so matching the comma is immaterial to the OP's requirement.  Thanks again.

Comment: This regex matches 20.5% because of the optionality of the decimal part

Comment: This regex works perfectly for the example that you gave us, but it doesn't get the `,` as a separator, just change the `(?:\.\d+)?` for `(?:[\.,]\d+)?`

Comment: OMG there's so much I do not know about regexp. Thank you Rob, thank you @JavierDiaz

Comment: I think the whitespaces shouldn't be required - and also they should be inside the lookahead

Comment: @enrico, I do not believe you are correct. Due to the requirement that the number be followed by one or more spaces, 20.5% will not match.

Comment: @rob, Yes, like that will not match, but the fact that a number must be followed by a space to be a number is wrong. This will not match numbers at the end of the string or numbers followed by anything that is not a space. For example the sentences "I have to pay 12.5$" or "The number is 5." contain numbers that are not percentages. So your regex works correctly for all the test cases that lorenzo provided, but will not work always.

Comment: @enrico.bacis You are right. However, your regexp match for any string that contains any type of number. @RobRaisch I can't get how edit `/\b\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?\b\s+(?!%|percent)/` to correct this bug Enrico reported.

Answer (score 7):

This is the robust way to do it, and it's also extracting the numbers.

```
(\b\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?\b(?!(?:[\.,]\d+)|(?:\s*(?:%|percent))))
```

It is similar to Rob's regex but it should work for all the cases.

```
(                          -- capturing block
  \b                       -- word boundary
  \d+                      -- one or more digits
  (?:[\.,]\d+)?            -- optionally followed by a period or a comma
                              and one or more digits
  \b                       -- word boundary
  (?!                      -- not followed by
    (?:[\.,]\d+)           -- a period or a comma and one or more digits
                              [that is the trick]
    |                      -- or
    (?:\s*(?:%|percent))   -- zero or more spaces and the % sign or 'percent'
  )
)
```

Comment: Haha, your one passed all the tests provided, and you were way faster than me, so +1 to you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of your negated character class:

```
/\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?!\s*(?:percent|%))/
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've used after reading Rob answer. Thank you, +1

Comment: @Bergi, Not to pick too many nits, but your solution will match: '10.1percent' which is probably not what is required. ;)