# Regex to match phrases not containing a palindrome

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to match a word *not* containing a palindrome (be it as long as it may)?

For instance, for a 6-character-long palindrome, *foo/bar* would match but *x**barrab**zz/1**xoxxox**a14* would not match.

Comment: Can you give one more example?

Comment: Yes, of course.

(for polynomial of length 2)

Match: hello, world, sun, x, mine, hola
Non-match: ohho, izzil, 112maam, 01221555

Comment: I think you mean *palindrome* (not "polynomial")

Comment: @Bohemian Amazingly embarassing. It's late :(

Comment: Would `xyx` be considered a palindrome?

Comment: @Rawing It would technically, yes. In this case, I don't really care about an optional middle character inside the palindrome, but wanted to know the technique in JS Regex.

Comment: The esasiest way to check if a string is a palindrom is often to reverse it and then compare the reversed version with the original.  "contains" is kind of ambiguous,

Comment: requirements seem ambiguous.  `racecar` is a palindrome but do you consider `a toyota race car` to contain palindromes ?

Comment: If the regex is looking for 1 captured character and an optional "middle" character, `oyo` would be considered a palindrome.
So in the phrase `a toyota race car`, the word `toyota` would match that palindrome. Therefore, the only word that would NOT contain a palindrome is `toyota` and it would not be matched. I am looking for words, basically, but not exclusively alpha-numeric. That's why I said phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\b(?:(?!(\w)(\w)\2?\1)\w)+\b`.

[Online Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/fI3xT9/1)

It's a simple negative lookahead that checks if the word contains a structure like `xyx` or `xyyx`.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.
I was under the impression that JS did not support negative lookahead for some reason (as asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851921/negative-lookahead-regular-expression)) and that was why Bohemian's solution did not work. Apparently not.

Comment: @GuyWaldman It probably didn't work because of the start-of-string and end-of-string anchors `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead, for example for length 5/6 (3-letter with middle letter reused or doubled):

```
^(?:(.)(?!(.)(.)\3?\2\1))*$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/fSOmNCn0Xi).

But you would have to add another look ahead for each length (which I leave as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: Still no, sorry. I tried using a negative lookahead on my own to no avail.

Comment: I've made another change, and tested it and it seems to work. But this is for 2.5 and 3 letter words only as an example. You would have to add in the others to a reasonable maximum length.

Comment: Right. Sorry, your solution is correct (and very much appreciated!).
I was aiming for Javascript regex and of course it wouldn't work on regex101 and on my tests because it doesn't support negative lookahead). Would you know of any JS solution?

Comment: @guy I don't think it can be done without a negative look ahead, because you can't use a back reference inside a negated character class, ie `[^\1]` doesn't work, and you need a way to disallow chars captured as a single-char group in specific positions.