# Inverse match for HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, regex-lookarounds

Using **NodeJS**, I have the following regex: `/<[^>]*>/g` which matches HTML tags:
([Live Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/KIC8hb/1))
[image]

I would like to inverse the match so it will capture the text, I've tried [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851921/negative-lookahead-regular-expression) approach, with no luck.

**EDIT**
I'm avoiding split method, because I need the indexes of the match

Is it possible with JS?

Comment: Split with the same regex.

Comment: Right, I've done it ... however I need the indexes of the matches

Comment: Link to live demo?

Comment: If you need the indexes, just match the tags and use end of last, and start of next tag as indices for the stuff in between?

Comment: See my edits or [click here](https://www.regex101.com/r/KIC8hb/1)

Comment: You may use [`/<[^>]*>|((?:(?!<[^>]*>)[\s\S])+)/g`](https://www.regex101.com/r/KIC8hb/3) and use the indices only when Group 1 matched.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried that approach, but failed to nail all the use cases, for example when the string end is not within the tag the last index should be the string length. I'm trying to avoid if else statements and rather stick with the regex power

Comment: So is this regex only designed to work on span tags with style attributes, or real world html, because if the later you will have issues

Comment: Talking about "regex power", it is not that powerful in JS. You will have to check with `if`/`else` in this case. Or use proper tools to work with HTML.

Comment: Please elaborate on your last comment.

Comment: `<p>Oh<br data-something="1>2">no!</p>`

Comment: basically I'm trying to tokenize parts of the text without touching the HTML formatting (which is basic formatting like bold italic or font-size attribute). for example <b>shlomi@gmail.com</b> would be <b>{{EMAIL}}</b>

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://www.regex101.com/r/KIC8hb/4)?

Comment: Looking good @ThomasAyoub I think this is it

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: Yes, but this is JS, its regex engine does not support lookbehinds. The only *regex* way is the one I showed above: match what you do not need and match *and capture* what you need.  Also,  tobias_k's idea is very good.

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz, you're in [tag:node], so use an HTML parsing lib like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). Regex is an inappropriate tool for handling HTML in this manner.

Comment: Right, I've missed the fact it is not JS

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-node-js

Comment: I'm aware of it, however virtual DOM seems overkill for my purpose, isn't it?

Comment: [This might work](https://www.regex101.com/r/QTpCYa/1) to replace the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible with JS?

No. HTML can be arbitrarily nested, which means you need recursion in order to consume it using regex - something which JavaScript regex doesn't have.

Assuming you can ditch JS and use a language that supports PCRE, this <strike>monstrous bunch of unintelligible characters written by Cthulhu</strike> regex does the trick ([mandatory regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/52Zm7Z/1)) (note that it doesn't deal with CDATA):

```
<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<([a-z]+)(?:\s\S+?=(["']|)[\s\S]*?\2)*>((?:[\s\S]*?(?R)?)*)<\/\1>
```

Here's how it works:

- `<!--[\s\S]*?-->|` is for preventing comments from causing false positives
- `<([a-z]+)(?:\s\S+?=(["']|)[\s\S]*?\2)*>` is the opening tag, where

  - `([a-z]+)` is the tag name (note the capturing group - we'll need it in the closing tag)
  - `(?:\s\S+?=(["']|)[\s\S]*?\2)*` is the attributes, where

    - `\s` is the whitespace character that separates attributes from tag name and each other
    - `\S+?=` is the attribute name followed by an equals sign (note the lazy quantifier - we need it because `\S` includes `=`)
    - `(["']|)[\s\S]*?\2` is the value, that can be enclosed in double quotes, single quotes, or nothing
- `((?:[\s\S]*?(?R)?)*)` is the text between tags (note the capturing group - **it's exactly what you need and will appear as group 3**), where `(?R)?` makes the regex able to deal with nested constructs
- `<\/\1>` is the closing tag, where `\1` is the tag name (remember the capturing group in the opening tag)

Answer (score 0):

Since given answers are not giving any solution, so you can use the following code for simplistic [x]html with no nested tags. Else, for complete solution use an HTML parser.

```js
var str = "Lorem ipsum <pre class='a1'>text 1</pre> Lorem ipsum <a href='http://google.com'>text 2</a>";
    str.replace(/<(\w+).*>(.*?)<\/\1>/g, function(match, g1, g2) { console.log(g2); });
```