# Regex - how to negate one word and one word only?

Tags: regex

How do I write a regex expression that matches these lines

```
<color>blue</color>
<color>green</color>
<color>blackish</color>
<color>offblack</color>
```

But not this

```
<color>black</color>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression that doesn't contain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string)

Comment: should it only match `<color>n</color>` (except where n = black) or ANY line  except <color>black</color> (I.e. would `I like turtles`) be match or a non-match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative lookahead Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851921/negative-lookahead-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

`^<color>((?!black).*?|black.+?)</color>$`

[Click here for a test / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pvnLPR/4)