# Regex : Find a character unless it is surrounded by double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to find a character such as ',' in a string unless it is surrounded by double quotes.

For example in the string: 
'Example, "String,"'

I would like it to match the comma after 'Example' but not after 'String'.

Is there a regex that can do this?

Comment: did you mean if the strings is exactly like "\n" or something like "something \n something else "?

Comment: Have added an example.Sorry about not adding one earlier.

Comment: If you're parsing CSV, regexes is usually not the way to go. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can negate a group of characters in regex by using `(?![text])`.

For example, something like `(?!"),(?!")` would find all the `,` that are not "touched" by `"`. You may need to check your string with multiple variations of this regex to get the desired result but I think you should be able to work wit the given example.

Comment: Do all browsers' javascript implementation handle negative lookahead?

Comment: This is wrong,because it don't work if remove space between `,` and "String,".`('Example,"String,"')`

Comment: @mplungjan Lookbehind is supported in ES2018. I couldn't find a standard in which lookahead support was added, but earlier stackoverflow questions suggest it has been implemented for a long time (for example [this question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851921/negative-lookahead-regular-expression)).

Comment: @Ehsan thank you for the comment, I clarified what the regex in my answer will find.

Comment: @Ehsan - that could possibly be non-interesting if all real commas were followed by a space

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
console.log(
  `For example in the string: 'Example, "String,"'`.match(/, /g).length,
  `For example, in the following string: 'Example, "String," I'd like to find all ","'`.match(/, /g).length,
)
```